# Need documentation or API reference to create job posts on Hirist platform

Tags: reference, postman, documentation, jira-rest-api, spring-social

I'm working on a project that involves job postings, and I need to integrate with the Hirist platform to create job posts programmatically. However, I couldn't find any official documentation or API reference for this process on the Hirist website or developer portal.

Can someone please guide me on where to find the documentation or API reference for creating job posts on Hirist? If there's a specific endpoint or SDK that I should be using, any information or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I was expecting to find official documentation or API references that outline the endpoints, request methods, parameters, and authentication mechanisms required to programmatically create job posts on Hirist.

Additionally, I was hoping to find examples or code snippets demonstrating how to use the Hirist API for job posting integration in a development project